# Java program to find GCD is slightly off

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that accepts 2 positive integers from the user, and will output the greatest common divisor of the two numbers inputted. Here is what I have:

```
package assignment1solutions;

import stdlib.StdIn;
import stdlib.StdOut;

public class FindGCD {
    public static long euclid(int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0) {
            return a;
        }
        return euclid(b, a%b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StdOut.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(StdIn.readLine());
        StdOut.print("Enter another positive integer: ");
        int b = Integer.parseInt(StdIn.readLine());
        StdOut.printf("The greatest common divisor is: %,d.", b,a%b);
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you "feel [it's] close but not quite right"?

Comment: You are not calling your `euclid` method at all. You can also use a `Scanner` to read `int`s from the input.

Comment: Can you provide us with some examples of your outputs so we can see what working and what is now?

Comment: @BoristheSpider By the looks of it, the are required to use that `StdIn` library  - it's included as `stdlib.StdIn` which a novice programmer (which OP is self described as) would not have created. It seems like their instructor/mentor is a C++ programmer who doesn't like to do things Java-esque.

Comment: As an example entering integers 4 and 14 would give GCD of 4 which isn't correct

Comment: Did you try to google and look at the second link? https://www.google.com/search?q=java+euclid+gcd&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use your code with a few tiny changes...

```
public static long euclid(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    }
    return euclid(b, a%b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
    int a = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine().trim());
    System.out.print("Enter another positive integer: ");
    int b = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine().trim());
    // Call euclid, and Fix the format string.
    System.out.printf("The greatest common divisor is: %d.", euclid(a,b));
}
```

Which I tested like so

```
Enter a positive integer: 120
Enter another positive integer: 50
The greatest common divisor is: 10.
```

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. You can take two numbers that are relatively primes to test (ex: 8, 5).

Comment: @ZouZou Switched back to OP's algorithm, and verified that 8,5 has a GCD of 1.

Comment: This part is wrong I think : `euclid(b,a%b)` at the initial call. In the function, it works just fine. But the initial call is wrong, so it should be `euclid(a, b)`. `euclid(b,a%b)` also doesn't match up with the function definition. I suppose it would help to have more descriptive variable names other than `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not even calling your `euclid` function. You have to call that functiin before the output is written.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling your `euclid` method. Also, you are always just printing the `b` value.

Change:

```
StdOut.printf("The greatest common divisor is: %,d.", b,a%b);
```

to:

```
StdOut.printf("The greatest common divisor is: %,d.", euclid(a, b));
// or    
System.out.printf("The greatest common divisor is: %,d.", euclid(a, b));
```